# TinyMce CSS - Applying css only in editor

Tags: tinymce

I am using content_css to link to all my css for my site.

This works and the content in the tiinyMce editor window is styled as per the css files.

My site has a header, content, footer layout and i apply specific styles to links in the content section like so...

```
.contentWrapper a { background: url ... etc
```

So these styles are not applied in the editor window as the links are not in a div with a class of contentWrapper.

I know i can create another css file and apply these styles directly to a tags in there and only reference it for tinyMCE but this would duplicate my site css.

is there anyway i can specify something like .tinyMce a { .. or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eighter you duplicate your css or you will need to load a second stylesheet with the diff.

Comment: Sorry, dont see the difference between the two statements you just described - surely i would have to load a second stylesheet in order to duplicate the css

Comment: the second css would only contain the diffs (no need to duplicate)

Comment: Well i would be duplicating the styles - if i could do it in one file it would be like .content a, .tinyMce a { blah }

Comment: Well its used inside another application that wraps it up N2 - so not really, but i am setting all my css files in the content_css property and this works.  I have no problem with that.  The problem is that some of my styles are set by container class, but the preview of this via the wysiwyg is not in the container.  ie .content a { ... }

Comment: you are aware of the fact that tinymce uses a contentedityble iframe in order to style content?

Comment: I realise it shows it in an IFrame, this is why i cant see the contents to find out how to style it.  This is what im asking.  Inside the IFrame, is there anything that i can use to style it , like a container class?

Comment: you could give tehe editor iframe body a class: $(ed.getBody()).addClass('my_special_class');

Comment: hum interesting - i take it it doesnt already have one?   will have to look in to this

Comment: the only thing is the class needs to be in content_css or another css file that you load directly into the editors iframe

Answer (score 0):

TinyMce hosts the editor in a iframe, I do not think you have a choice here. in order to affect the editor, you must load the css into the iframe.